# JSP prepared insert statement

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, jdbc

Hello everybody im having troubles with this createUser method in my JSP.

It works locally on my glassfish server, when i then deploy it on my schools server. Everything runs fine except this method. I dont know why, ive tried debugging it locally and the boolean createUser return true. But it seems that when deployed it returns false, and gets redirected to the test.jsp site. My question is has anyone else had the same problem? And is there a way to show the exception from the server in a file, in the browser. Its hard to fix a problem when you dont know where to look. I really hope someone can help, all help is appreciated.

Thx in advance

```
public static boolean createUser(String fname, String lname, String email, String user, String pwd) throws SQLException {
        PreparedStatement pst = null;
        Connection connection = ConnectionProvider.getConnection();

        try {
            String Query = "INSERT INTO members (first_name, last_name, email, uname, pass) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
            pst = connection.prepareStatement(Query);
            pst.setString(1, fname);
            pst.setString(2, lname);
            pst.setString(3, email);
            pst.setString(4, user);
            pst.setString(5, pwd);

            pst.executeUpdate();
            //connection.commit();

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.out.println("createUser failed " + ex.getMessage());
            return false;

        } finally {

            try {
                if (pst != null) {
                    pst.close();
                }
                if (connection != null) {
                    connection.close();
                }

            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                System.out.println("createUser - finally failed " + ex.getMessage());
            }
        }
        return true;
    }


//registration.jsp
<%
    String fname = request.getParameter("fname");
    String lname = request.getParameter("lname");
    String email = request.getParameter("email");
    String user = request.getParameter("uname");
    String pwd = request.getParameter("pass");
    session.setAttribute("userid", user);
    //MemberProvider.createUser(fname, lname, email, user, pwd);
    //response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
    boolean createUser = MemberProvider.createUser(fname, lname, email, user, pwd);
    //if (MemberProvider.createUser(fname, lname, email, user, pwd))
    if (createUser){
        response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
    } else {
        response.sendRedirect("test.jsp");
    }
%>
```

I finally found the stacktrace on the server, Took quiet some time.

```
2015-01-04 14:49:54.332:INFO:oejsl.ELContextCleaner:Scanner-0: javax.el.BeanELResolver purged
2015-01-04 14:49:54.332:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:Scanner-0: Stopped o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@3b970fb6{/kristian3e14,file:/home/kristian3e14/kristian3e14/,UNAVAILABLE}{/home/kristian3e14/kristian3e14}
2015-01-04 14:49:54.400:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:Scanner-0: Started o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@48197a77{/kristian3e14,file:/home/kristian3e14/kristian3e14/,AVAILABLE}{/home/kristian3e14/kristian3e14}
2015-01-04 14:49:56.352:INFO:oejsl.ELContextCleaner:Scanner-0: javax.el.BeanELResolver purged
2015-01-04 14:49:56.352:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:Scanner-0: Stopped o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@48197a77{/kristian3e14,file:/home/kristian3e14/kristian3e14/,UNAVAILABLE}{/home/kristian3e14/kristian3e14}
2015-01-04 14:49:56.430:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:Scanner-0: Started o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@42270653{/kristian3e14,file:/home/kristian3e14/kristian3e14/,AVAILABLE}{/home/kristian3e14/kristian3e14}
2015-01-04 14:50:05.445:INFO:oejsl.ELContextCleaner:Scanner-0: javax.el.BeanELResolver purged
2015-01-04 14:50:05.445:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:Scanner-0: Stopped o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@42270653{/kristian3e14,file:/home/kristian3e14/kristian3e14/,UNAVAILABLE}{/home/kristian3e14/kristian3e14}
2015-01-04 14:50:05.548:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:Scanner-0: Started o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@104ddfcd{/kristian3e14,file:/home/kristian3e14/kristian3e14/,AVAILABLE}{/home/kristian3e14/kristian3e14}
createUser failed Field 'admin' doesn't have a default value
Fejl i createuser
createUser failed Field 'admin' doesn't have a default value
Fejl i createuser
2015-01-04 15:08:20.911:INFO:oejsl.ELContextCleaner:Scanner-0: javax.el.BeanELResolver purged
2015-01-04 15:08:20.911:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:Scanner-0: Stopped o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@104ddfcd{/kristian3e14,file:/home/kristian3e14/kristian3e14/,UNAVAILABLE}{/home/kristian3e14/kristian3e14}
2015-01-04 15:08:20.967:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:Scanner-0: Started o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@35852e05{/kristian3e14,file:/home/kristian3e14/kristian3e14/,AVAILABLE}{/home/kristian3e14/kristian3e14}
2015-01-04 15:08:31.011:INFO:oejsl.ELContextCleaner:Scanner-0: javax.el.BeanELResolver purged
2015-01-04 15:08:31.011:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:Scanner-0: Stopped o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@35852e05{/kristian3e14,file:/home/kristian3e14/kristian3e14/,UNAVAILABLE}{/home/kristian3e14/kristian3e14}
2015-01-04 15:08:31.101:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:Scanner-0: Started o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@3c2c57ec{/kristian3e14,file:/home/kristian3e14/kristian3e14/,AVAILABLE}{/home/kristian3e14/kristian3e14}
createUser failed Field 'admin' doesn't have a default value
2015-01-04 15:50:39.448:INFO:oejsl.ELContextCleaner:Scanner-0: javax.el.BeanELResolver purged
2015-01-04 15:50:39.449:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:Scanner-0: Stopped o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@3c2c57ec{/kristian3e14,file:/home/kristian3e14/kristian3e14/,UNAVAILABLE}{/home/kristian3e14/kristian3e14}
2015-01-04 15:50:39.506:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:Scanner-0: Started o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@490ce325{/kristian3e14,file:/home/kristian3e14/kristian3e14/,AVAILABLE}{/home/kristian3e14/kristian3e14}
2015-01-04 15:50:51.571:INFO:oejsl.ELContextCleaner:Scanner-0: javax.el.BeanELResolver purged
2015-01-04 15:50:51.572:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:Scanner-0: Stopped o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@490ce325{/kristian3e14,file:/home/kristian3e14/kristian3e14/,UNAVAILABLE}{/home/kristian3e14/kristian3e14}
2015-01-04 15:50:51.656:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:Scanner-0: Started o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@79ee9e62{/kristian3e14,file:/home/kristian3e14/kristian3e14/,AVAILABLE}{/home/kristian3e14/kristian3e14}
createUser failed Field 'admin' doesn't have a default value
2015-01-04 16:02:37.184:INFO:oejsl.ELContextCleaner:Scanner-0: javax.el.BeanELResolver purged
2015-01-04 16:02:37.184:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:Scanner-0: Stopped o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@79ee9e62{/kristian3e14,file:/home/kristian3e14/kristian3e14/,UNAVAILABLE}{/home/kristian3e14/kristian3e14}
2015-01-04 16:02:37.341:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:Scanner-0: Started o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@43bff0e1{/kristian3e14,file:/home/kristian3e14/kristian3e14/,AVAILABLE}{/home/kristian3e14/kristian3e14}
2015-01-04 16:02:38.353:INFO:oejsl.ELContextCleaner:Scanner-0: javax.el.BeanELResolver purged
2015-01-04 16:02:38.353:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:Scanner-0: Stopped o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@43bff0e1{/kristian3e14,file:/home/kristian3e14/kristian3e14/,UNAVAILABLE}{/home/kristian3e14/kristian3e14}
2015-01-04 16:02:38.446:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:Scanner-0: Started o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@223afbaa{/kristian3e14,file:/home/kristian3e14/kristian3e14/,AVAILABLE}{/home/kristian3e14/kristian3e14}
createUser failed Field 'admin' doesn't have a default value
Jan 04, 2015 4:02:58 PM org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler generateClass
SEVERE: Error compiling file: /tmp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8090-kristian3e14-_kristian3e14-any-/jsp/org/apache/jsp/test_jsp.java
2015-01-04 16:02:58.521:WARN:oejs.ServletHandler:qtp1561907217-22: 
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: PWC6033: Error in Javac compilation for JSP||PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 9 in the jsp file: /test.jsp|PWC6199: Generated servlet error:|inconvertible types|  required: boolean|  found:    java.lang.Object||
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:129)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:299)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateClass(Compiler.java:392)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:453)
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:625)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:374)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:492)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:378)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:698)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:505)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:564)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1096)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:432)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:175)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1030)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:201)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:109)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:445)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:268)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.run(AbstractConnection.java:358)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:601)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:532)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Comment: what's the exception/error?

Comment: Please don't use `System.out.println("createUser failed " + ex.getMessage());` to handle exceptions, it's so naive that it doesn't provide enough info to solve it. At least use `ex.printStacktrace()` to see the whole error message, then as an option use a proper logger to log the exception in a proper log file.

Comment: By the way, we need to check the stacktrace to analyse the issues in your piece of code.

Comment: did you deploy the database? when you deployed on server., and other database config, username/password ... etc

Comment: The database is deployed and everything else works. Its just this method, when i run it without redirecting it just shows a blank page. But im stil not sure how do i get the error message displayed. When i debug locally i can se everything in the console. But how do i view it when its deployed and im running it from my browser

Comment: When you deploy your application on server, its user id and pwd change according to your database server check that first, then check you have connectivity with database server? provide stack trace for debug your issue

Comment: @Learningftw so when you say *The database is deployed and everything else works. Its just this method* you really mean *The database engine is installed, my database was deployed and it's properly installed, my application connects to the database using proper credentials and there are other functionalities in the app that uses the database connection and works, except for this single part* right? If so, please make it clear in the question rather than in comments. And again, change the line I pointed out in a previous comment by `ex.printStacktrace()` and redeploy your app

Comment: Im not sure what your saying in the first part, i have login, admin checks, updates ex. All works fine. And when i check in putty, all the changes are made that should be made. How do i create a stacktrace when the JSP page is deployed. Im just viewing a webpage. This is what im unsure of.

Comment: *How do I create a stacktrace when the JSP page is deployed*? You can't. Two things: 1) To reply somebody in comments, use `@username` so the person will be noticed. 2) Open your project in your IDE, make the change in the code, recompile it, generate the war, redeploy the war in your application server, retest your app. Then, the stacktrace will be printed to the logs in glassfish. Also, specify the version of glassfish you're using to determine the location of the log files.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Thanks alot for your time and patience. Im kinda new to asking questions in here. Ive change the sout to ex.printStackTrace(), and im running "GlassFish Server Open Source Edition  4.1"

Comment: Ok, after deployment of your artifact and testing this functionality, from the folder where glassfish is installed (let's call it `gfinstall`), go to `gfinstall/glassfish/domains/domain1/logs/` and there should be a log file there, probably called server.log. Open the file and the stacktrace should be there. COpy the stacktrace and paste it here.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza My problem with this is that its a server hosted at my school, so i dont really have the possibility of accessing this archive which in this case is really unfortunate. Is there another way to view the stacktrace - and usually the error message shows on the browser. But since it shows a blank page its hard to figure out what to do.

Comment: *My problem with this is that its a server hosted at my school, so i dont really have the possibility of accessing this archive which in this case is really unfortunate* I don't really think so, in fact you are able to do it since glassfish it's just a folder with a main jar file (and lot of other jars for functionalities that maybe you will never use) that is executed by the JVM and I don't think you don't have enough permissions to access to it. If you still insist in that you can't (because you don't explain a technical reason that stops you) then configure a logger in your app

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Actually this is gonna sound kinda strange. But i dont think glassfish is installed on the server, and it still works. So what ive been told is that when im using it locally, im using glassfish but on the server im using Jetty. i dont know if this is correct though.

Comment: Oh ok, then go to the folder where Jetty is installed, locate the log file (this shouldn't be hard enough to find in a SEO) and check it out. If you find the stacktrace there, edit the question and paste the stacktrace.

Comment: the only thing i can find is a tmp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8090-kristian3e14-_kristian3e14-any-

Where the others are named hsperfdata_username, dont know if this is a problem with the way i deployed it

In this folder there are 4 classes of my JSP, but it doesent seem like its a log, it just seems like how it compiles the JSP on the server

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Thx alot for the help man! Worked like a charm.. Have a great day :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that
It was because i had implicit null as my admin, when i look for my admin its 1 if your an admin. So it needed af value for it.

So i just changed it to the below and it worked. Thx alot for all the help:)

```
   public static boolean createUser(String fname, String lname, String email, String user, String pwd) {
        PreparedStatement pst = null;
        Connection connection = ConnectionProvider.getConnection();

        try {
            String Query = "INSERT INTO members (first_name, last_name, email, uname, pass, admin) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
            pst = connection.prepareStatement(Query);
            pst.setString(1, fname);
            pst.setString(2, lname);
            pst.setString(3, email);
            pst.setString(4, user);
            pst.setString(5, pwd);
            pst.setString(6, "0");
            pst.executeUpdate();
            //connection.commit();

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return false;

        } finally {

            try {
                if (pst != null) {
                    pst.close();
                }
                if (connection != null) {
                    connection.close();
                }

            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

This worked :)